# Regex: Get subtext from a string

Tags: regex

I have a list of text lines. Each line contains a title and a URL as follows:

```
product-title-7134    http://domain.com/page-1
another-product-title-822 http://domain.com/page-218
etc.
```

Using only .NET regex, please help me extract the url from each line.
I understand it can be done by looking at the string from the end until the `http` is met and output that part but I don't know the exact regex formula for that. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `\s+(\S+)$` should give you URL in match group #1

Comment: There is a great tool. Check this out: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: You need the overloaded method that returns the Match object. All parts of your regex that enclosed in parentheses will be added to Groups collection of the Match object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with this regex:

```
http://(\S+)
```

And find first group in every match.

Comment: I think he wants the http:// prefix included, so I would do `(http://\S+)` and get the first group in every match.

Comment: Yea, he should deduce what he wants

Answer (score 0):

This regex will math all `https://` and `http://` links:

```
(http|https)(://\S+)
```

You can test this in the .NET regex tester: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Using only one group: `(https?://\S+)`